# How is IEEE754 float implemented in Python?

Tags: floating-point, python-3.6, ieee-754

How is IEEE754 implemented in python?
I was very confused.

If 0.1+0.2 can't equal 0.3,shouldn't 0.1+0.1 also not equal 0.2?

Why does this happen only in a few decimal calculations?
Shouldn't it happen in all of them?

Here is my sample code using Python on the console

[image]

Comment: Python will use whatever floating point support the hardware provides.  Usually that is IEEE 754 binary floating point, which can only represent integer multiples of a power of 2,  and all numbers that can't be exactly represented will be represented by the nearest fp value, which will be slightly smaller or slightly larger.  These "rounding errors" may compound or cancel whenever you add numbers.

Comment: Is there a detailed documentation of how to handle such "rounding errors"？

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163)

Comment: Thank you! I think I've also found python's official description of this

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues